# Get Invalid json after response.json

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest

Im really new in Programming with JS. I want to implement an Soccer Bet Game. I use react-native for programming the app.

After fetching my restapi with Postman I get this result as response from my nodejs Server:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userid": 1,
        "email": "Test@test.de",
        "username": "testnutzer"
    },
    "seasons": [
        {
            "seasonid": 3,
            "startingyear": 2020,
            "competitionid": 1,
            "competitionname": "1. Bundesliga",
            "competitionsymbol": "1BULI"
        },
        {
            "seasonid": 5,
            "startingyear": 2020,
            "competitionid": 2,
            "competitionname": "2. Bundesliga",
            "competitionsymbol": "2BULI"
        },
        {
            "seasonid": 9,
            "startingyear": 2021,
            "competitionid": 4,
            "competitionname": "Europameisterschaft",
            "competitionsymbol": "EM"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I fetch it with Javascript Code and the fetch api the json is invalid:

```
Object {
  "seasons": Array [
    Object {
      "competitionid": 1,
      "competitionname": "1. Bundesliga",
      "competitionsymbol": "1BULI",
      "seasonid": 3,
      "startingyear": 2020,
    },
    Object {
      "competitionid": 2,
      "competitionname": "2. Bundesliga",
      "competitionsymbol": "2BULI",
      "seasonid": 5,
      "startingyear": 2020,
    },
    Object {
      "competitionid": 4,
      "competitionname": "Europameisterschaft",
      "competitionsymbol": "EM",
      "seasonid": 9,
      "startingyear": 2021,
    },
  ],
  "user": Object {
    "email": "Test@test.de",
    "userid": 1,
    "username": "testnutzer",
  },
}
```

Here is my JS-Code:

```
fetch(URL_GET_USER_SEASONS, {
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        key: key,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: What's invalid about it?

Comment: the "Object" in the Second is not valid json

Comment: At that point it's no longer JSON but a JS object. The words `Object` and `Array` are only there to help identify them in the console log